# План действий по настройке поддомена

Tags: сервер, nginx, dns, домен, поддомены

У меня имеются:

- `IP адрес` и на нём `VPS` сервер с Линуксом, от российской компании; имеется `SSL`.
- Доменное имя от зарубежного регистратора доменных имён.

Я хочу создать поддомен с отсылкой на тот же IP и сервер. Например, чтобы у регистратора указать поддомен со ссылкой на мой `IP` и порт, по которому на своём VPS привязать программу. Однако такой вариант кажется невозможным – у регистратора домены и поддомены могут ссылаться либо на другой домен, либо на `IP`, без портов.

Какие в принципе есть варианты решения этой задачи? Можно ли с домена и поддомена перенаправлять запросы на мой `IP` и сервер так, чтобы там их распределять по портам, используя какой-нибудь `Nginx`? Или как на одном `VPS` привязать несколько `IP`, как-то их распределять? И как в каждом случае настроить `SSL`?

Comment: вопрос слишком общий и весьма сумбурный: в одну кучу у вас свалены и поддомены, и ip-адреса, и порты, да ещё и к чему-то ssl. задайте, пожалуйста, **конкретный** вопрос, нажав [edit]

Comment: @alexanderbarakin это не куча, а конкретный вопрос о том, как настроить поддомен с указанными нюансами. С меньшими нюансами или вообще без них задача становится тривиальной, с кучей решений в сети.

Comment: так изложите **один** из множества перечисленных вами шагов, который вызывает у вас трудность. помните, что данный сайт —база знаний, и вопросы (с ответами на них) должны быть полезны не только спросившему.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin проблема с единственным описанным шагом: *план действий*. И весь мой вопрос заключается в первых трёх строчках описания и предложениях _"Я хочу создать поддомен с отсылкой на тот же IP и сервер"_ и _"Какие в принципе есть варианты решения этой задачи?"_ Всё остальное лишь моё примерное видение возможных решений.

Comment: план действий изложил. если в нём осталось что-то непонятное — спрашивайте (логичнее под самим ответом), постараюсь подкорректировать ответ для лучшего понимания.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin спасибо большое) я попробую всё настроить и отпишусь в виде галочки или коммента.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Я хочу создать поддомен с отсылкой на тот же IP и сервер (требуется план действий)

план:

1. добавляете у регистратора поддомен(ы) с *a*-записью, ведущей на тот же ip
2. устанавливаете какой-нибудь http-сервер (из ныне популярных стоит упомянуть *apache* и *nginx*)
3. настраиваете в конфигурации установленного http-сервера приём и обработку запросов для поддомена(-ов) (например, директива *virtualhost* у *apache* или директива *server* у *nginx*)
4. при необходимости получаете сертификат(ы) и настраиваете обработку ssl для этого поддомена(-ов)